# Why when I share csv file to another app, that app give me error message?

Tags: java, android, csv

**when I shared the CSV file with another app, I got a message from that app that say unsupported attachment**

#### here is the main activity code

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder=new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
            File csvFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SalesManagerBackup/"+"inventoryBackup.csv");
            if (!csvFile.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.there_is_no_data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Intent intentShare=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intentShare.setType("text/csv");
                intentShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://"+csvFile));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShare,getResources().getString(R.string.share_data_to_other_device)));
```

}

#### Here is the Manifest Code

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.autofocus" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Light"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[the message when I share to app][1]

Comment: `Uri.parse("file://"+csvFile))` You cannot use a file uri anymore. Use FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: How can I use  FileProvider?

Comment: FileProvider.getUriForFile(file);